Getting "unable to find the type of initialisation. kindly specify one"
I am trying to retrieve the current user details in my Catalyst Node function using the method when getCurrentUser(). But when executing the function, I am getting the error

unable to find the type of initialisation. kindly specify one

I tried re-running the function by reloading the function URL still getting the same error.

You might have faced this issue if you have not passed the req object when you initialized the Catalyst SDK since the SDK was unable to initialize properly
let catalystapp = catalyst.initialize();

To resolve this issue, you can pass the (req) object to the initialize() method. For example:
let catalystapp = catalyst.initialize(req);

You can find the official help documentation for initializing the Catalyst Node SDK here.
